# Rails app removes column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, mongrel

My ruby on rails application does some weird things which i could not understand why.

I am adding a column to a present table through migrations. Here is the mig:

```
 class AddSomeColumnToSomewhere < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   add_column :somehwhere, :mynewcol, :boolean, :default => false
 end

  def self.down
    remove_column :somehwhere, :mynewcol
 end
end
```

After running this migration i check the db, everything is fine. However, after i run the application, the column disappears.

Why can sth like that happen?

Thanks.

Comment: try change `:somehwhere` to `:somehwheres`, table name is pluralize.

Comment: the real one is actually plural. The migration does already his job. The problem is, the column will be removed after i start the application. Why is that? Do i have to add the column to the model as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is removing the column knowingly. To ensure, i think, the integrity. Thanks for the answers.